# C# processing queue in Silverlight 4

Tags: c#, silverlight, task-queue

I have the need to create a queue-based system where multiple threads will add actions to be processed by the queue.

Sounds simple enough, but my actions will be asynchronous (with animations) so I do not want to start the next action in the queue until the animation of the previous action is completed.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can make an `IAction` interface with an `Execute` method and a `Completed` event.

You can then make a queue of `IAction`s and pop and `Execute` the next item in the `Completed` handler for the current item.

You can even make an iterator method that `yield return`s `IAction`s and have the queue call `MoveNext()` after each `IAction` finishes.

**EDIT**: For example:

```
class ActionEnumerator : IAction {
    readonly IEnumerator<IAction> enumerator;
    public ActionEnumerator(IEnumerator<IAction> enumerator) {
        this.enumerator = enumerator;
    }

    public void Execute() {
        //If the enumerator gives us another action,
        //hook up its Completed event to continue the
        //the chain, then execute it.
        if (enumerator.MoveNext()) {
            enumerator.Current.Completed += delegate { Execute(); };
            enumerator.Current.Execute();
        } else     //If the enumerator didn't give us another action, we're finished.
            OnCompleted();
    }
}

IEnumerator<IAction> SomeMethod() { 
    ...
    yield return new SomeAction();
    //This will only run after SomeAction finishes
    ...
    yield return new OtherAction();
    ...
}
```

Comment: certainly sounds like you know what needs to be done here :) Thanks, do you think you could elaborate a little on the `yield` bit?

Comment: yeld is the keyword for implementing IEnumerable<T> or IEnumerable. Allows you to do foreach on your sequence of objectes in a custom manner.